# How can I separate a FASTA file into multiple exon and CDS files?

Tags: python, string, function, file, loops

I have a gff3 file and a FASTA genome file

The gff3 file is like this:

```
20 protein2genome exon 12005 12107 . - . ID=Blah_exon:1;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 12108 12200 . - . ID=Blah_exon:2;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 12005 12107 . - . ID=Blah_exon:3;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 12342 12542 . - . ID=Blah_exon:4;Name=Blah:1;Parent=Blah

20 protein2genome exon 13005 13107 . - . ID=ABC_exon:1;Name=ABC:1;Parent=ABC
```

For each exon, I need to write a new file named gene_name_exon_number.fa

The header inside the file is this:

> gene_name exon_number  chromosome_name exon_start   exon_end

followed by the nucleotide bases in its chromosome using the start and end numbers

So the first exon file would look like:

> Blah 1 20 12005 12107
>   ACGGGCCTCAAAGCCGCGACACGACGGCTGTCGGCCGGTAACAGTAACCCCGGAGTGAACTCCTAT

Each exon will be a new file.

Also, I need to create a CDS file for each gene containing all the exons named gene_name_cds.fa

The header inside the file is this:

> gene_name number_of_exons chromosome_name cds_start cds_end cds_total_length

So the first CDS file would look like:

> Blah 4 20 12005 12542
>   ACGGGCCTCAAAGCCGCGACACGACGGCTGTCGGCCGGTAACAGTAACCCCGGAGTGAACTCCTAT
>   ACGGGCCTCAAAGCCGCGACACGACGGCTGTCGGCCGGTAACAGTAACCCCGGAGTGAACTCCTAT

Note: the nucleotide bases are just all of the nucleotide bases from the exons pasted together.

In the end, there will be several exon files and one CDS file for EACH gene in a GFF3 file containing several hundred genes and thousands of exons.

However, the file is generating CDS files in the gigabtye range when the entire genome file is only 130mb. So the problem must be for loop order. Can someone help me fix the loop order?

I tried to use several for loops and prepender. My code looks like this so far:

```
import fileinput

input_file = "dummy.gf3"
search_file = "dummy.fa"

def line_pre_adder(filename, line_to_prepend):
    f = fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1)
    for xline in f:
        if f.isfirstline():
            print line_to_prepend.rstrip('\r\n') + '\n' + xline,
        else:
           print xline,

def exon_extractor():

exon_file = open(input_file)
for exon_line in exon_file:
    previous = ""
    CDS_exon_number = 1
    CDS_start = int(0)
    CDS_end = int(0)
    NMID = exon_line.split()[-1].split()[0].rsplit(';')[0][3:].rsplit("_")[0]
    exon_number = str(exon_line.split()[-1].split()[0].rsplit(';')[0][-1])
    filename = str(exon_line.split()[-1].split()[0].rsplit(';')[0][3:-2]) + "_" + str(exon_line.split()[-1].split()[0].rsplit(';')[0][-1])
    chromosome = exon_line.split()[0]
    start = exon_line.split()[3]
    end = str(int(exon_line.split()[4])+1)
    exon_header = ">" + NMID + " " + exon_number + " " + start + " " + str(int(end)-1)
    exon_file = open (str("exon_folder" + filename + ".fas"),"w+")
    cds_file = open (str("test_folder" + NMID +"_CDS" + ".fas"),"a+")
    exon_file.write(exon_header + '\n')
    desired = int(end) - int(start)
    with open (search_file,'r') as genome_file:         
        for genome_line in genome_file:
            if str(chromosome + " ") in genome_line:
                for genome_line in genome_file:
                    for i in range (int(desired)/60):
                        exon_file.write(genome_line.rstrip())

                        if NMID != previous:
                            cds_file.close()
                            line_pre_adder(str("test_folder" + NMID +"_CDS" + ".fas"), str(NMID + " " + str(CDS_exon_number) + " " + str(CDS_start) + " " + str(CDS_end) + " " + str(CDS_end-CDS_start)))
                            cds_file = open (str("test_folder" + NMID +"_CDS" + ".fas"),"a+")
                            cds_file.write(genome_line.rstrip())
                            previous = NMID
                            CDS_exon_number = exon_number
                            CDS_start += int(start)
                            CDS_end += (int(end)-1)
                        else:
                            cds_file.write(genome_line.rstrip())
                            CDS_exon_number = exon_number
                            CDS_start += int(start)
                            CDS_end += (int(end)-1)

                    if (int(desired) % 60) != 0:
                        exon_file.write(genome_line[0:(int(desired) % 60)+1].rstrip())
                        cds_file.write(genome_line[0:(int(desired) % 60)+1].rstrip())
                        break

                    else:
                        pass
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: You may want to use a standard package do this instead of reinventing the wheel.  For example, for GFF parsing use [bcbio-gff](https://github.com/chapmanb/bcbb/tree/master/gff) which is soon to be integrated into [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython), which can be used for fasta writing.  And [here's a good GFF parsing tutorial](http://biopython.org/wiki/GFF_Parsing) from biopython.

Comment: As for your question, I would recommend fixing the indentation problems and removing the comments in the snippet provided above.

Comment: @wflynny I fixed the indentation and removed the comments. I tried using bcbio-gff earlier but it didn't help. Bedtools didn't help either.